# Single code for OpenGL ES 2.0 and OpenGL ES 3.0

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Situation: Android application supports two versions of OpenGL ES: 2.0 and 3.0. Differences are only in shaders. I do not want to make separate sets of classes for versions 2 and 3, but want merge them. That is, instead of two similar classes:

```
import android.opengl.GLES20;
class ObjectGLES20 {
    public ObjectGLES20() {
        ...
        // invoke static methods from GLES20
        int positionLink = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programObject, "a_position");
        int lightPositionLink = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programObject, "u_lightPosition");
        ...
    }
}

import android.opengl.GLES30;
class ObjectGLES30 {
    public ObjectGLES30() {
        ...
        // invoke static methods from GLES30
        int positionLink = GLES30.glGetAttribLocation(programObject, "a_position");
        int lightPositionLink = GLES30.glGetUniformLocation(programObject, "u_lightPosition");
        ...
    }
}
```

Do something like this:

```
// define supported version OpenGL ES
if (getVersionGLES() >= 3.0 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) { 
    objectAll = new ObjectAll(new GLES30(), true) // use polymorphism
} else objectAll = new ObjectAll(new GLES20(), false)
...
/** @param gles - instance of GLES20 or GLES30 */
class ObjectAll {
    public ObjectAll(GLES20 gles, boolean isSupportGLES30) {
        String pathToVertexShader;
        String pathToFragmentShader;
        if (isSupportGLES30) {
            pathToVertexShader = "shaders/gles30/vertex_shader.glsl";
            pathToFragmentShader = "shaders/gles30/fragment_shader.glsl";
        } else {
            pathToVertexShader = "shaders/gles20/vertex_shader.glsl";
            pathToFragmentShader = "shaders/gles20/fragment_shader.glsl";
        }
        int programObject = linkProgram(pathToVertexShader, pathToFragmentShader);
        ...
        // invoke static methods from GLES20 or GLES30 depending on supported version
        // TIP!: static member accessed via instance reference
        int positionLink = gles.glGetAttribLocation(programObject, "a_position");
        int lightPositionLink = gles.glGetUniformLocation(programObject, 
            "u_lightPosition");
        ...
    }
}
```

But this approach (create instances GLES) seems not good for calling static methods. Maybe there are other options, such as reflection or others? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this approach seems not good for calling static methods GLES.

The Android `GLES30` object is a subclass of `GLES20`, and the underlying native API doesn't make such a distinction and the same native function will be used for both.

I strongly suspect it really doesn't matter and you can safely call `GLES20.glFoo()` for the functions and constants that are only in `GLES20` and it will work fine for both `GLES20` and `GLES30` content.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! If I understand you correctly, is it permissible to use the GLES20 static functions everywhere in the project, and make a choice only between versions of shaders (GLSL 1 and GLSL 3)?

Comment: Yes, unless you actually do want to use a `GLES30` only function or constant of course, in which case you'll need to use a later static instance.